# Laravel GraphQL Access an Arg inside args Function

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-8

I'm building a project with Laravel 8 and installed `https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel` in order to use GraphQL in my project. I have a mutation called 'UpdateUserMutation' which extends from Mutation, and it has an args function to retrieve data that the user sent. Basically, it looked like this;

````
    public function args(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'rules' => [
                    'required',
                    'numeric',
                    'exists:users'
                ]
            ],

            'name' => [
                'name' => 'name',
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'rules' => [
                    'string',
                    'min:3',
                    'max:191'
                ]
            ],

            'email' => [
                'name' => 'email',
                'type' => Type::string(),
                'rules' => [
                    'string',
                    'min:3',
                    'max:191',
                    'email:rfc,dns',
                    'unique:users,email,' . 'id'
                ]
            ],

            'department_id' => [
                'name' => 'department_id',
                'type' => Type::int(),
                'rules' => [
                    'numeric',
                    'exists:departments,id'
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```

I define Laravel validation rules inside of each element. I need to define the 'unique' rule for the email field but of course, I need to exclude that user's email address if the user doesn't change his/her email address. So, I need to access the id element which is inside args function. How can I do that?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass anonymous function to rules. Please check code below, I have fixed.

```
[
    'name' => 'email',
    'type' => Type::string(),
    'rules' => function($args) {
        return [
        'string',
        'min:3',
        'max:191',
        'email:rfc,dns',
        'unique:users,email,' . $args['id'] . ',id'
        ]; 
    }
]
```